# Synchronization and downsampling after matched filtering - GNURadio polyphase clock sync

Tags: downsampling, gnuradio

I am trying to model a QPSK transmission. For this, I am using the software GnuRadio and more specifically the block polyphase clock sync. This block performs timing synchronization for PAM signals by minimizing the derivative of the filtered signal. I modelised this on Matlab (for BPSK but that is the same problem) and here is a plot of the signal at the reception after matched filtering :
[image: Signal at the reception after the matched filtering]
The FIR used here is a Root Raised Cosine. The thing is that the polyphase clock sync will find the minimum derivative of this signal to know where to downsample but this is for me not the right location. Indeed, if we look on the matlab plot of the signal above, the minimum derivative is located between the two first 1 bits samples and not at the locations of these two samples...

For example, here below we try to send the bits 101001. Between the two first 1 bits, there is a maximum that the block will find as the location to sample... 
With GnuRadio, I use the simple blocks : 
[image: Gnu Radio blocks]
which give me the plot : 
[image: Plots of the downsampled signal at reception after being synchronized]
We see that this does not sample at the right place and does not return the right bits. Is there a problem in my comprehension of this block or of the way polyphase filters work?

Here are the parameters used on GNU Radio which are not visible on the picture above :

RRC : firdes.root_raised_cosine(gain,L,1,alpha,ntaps)

L = oversampling factor

Constellation : 00 = -1-1j, 01 = -1+1j, 10 = 1-1j, 11 = 1+1j

If I change the value of "Output SPS" (Output Samples per Symbol, to downsample) in the polyphase clock sync and replace it by the oversampling factor L, there is no decimation done and I obviously obtain the good signal which is actually a convolution between my delta of dirac + or -1 and a raised cosine : 
[image: Matched filtered signal, not downsampled]
This is actually this signal which has to be sampled at the right places to find the good original bits. Nevertheless I have the impression that the real part has become the imaginary part and vice versa : real part should be the bits 110 and imaginary part 001. This is the opposite here and I do not see why.

EDIT following the question of @Marcus Müller : Here is the plot of the signal after the block constellation modulator (which upsamples and applies the RRC FIR filter for the pulse shaping) :
[image: Plot of the signal after the constellation modulator block]
EDIT 2 : Here is the signal obtained by replacing the polyphase clock sync block by a FIR RRC block which shows it works perfectly. The problem is that it does not synchronize the signal :
[image: Plot of the signal after the RRC FIR block]

Comment: have you only tried this with six modulated bits? Could you try with a few more? This is a filter system, and you're literally asking for a 32 tap filter size in the synchronizer block, so the system simply needs a bit of data to synchronize to.

Comment: (especially, the low-derivative sections in your Matlab plot would never happen during a longer transmission – they are an artifact of what you decided to plot!)

Comment: ah, wait, can you also add a plot of the output ofthe constellation modulator?

Comment: Actually the sequence of bits 101001 is repeated as you can see in the block "Vector Source" with the option repeat. The 32 taps are maybe not enough : I would change it by the value ntaps = 2*L*3 so that the filter samples are from -3T to 3T, T being the symbol period.

Comment: I add the plot of the signal after the constellation modulator in my post above as an edit

Comment: huh! something seems to be broken with the constellation modulator: 10 samples from each "proper" maximum, there's a zero – but that's where the next PSK symbol should be!

Comment: For me the constellation modulator upsamples by adding L-1=9 zeros between each symbol + or - 1 and then convolutes with a RRC signal. This does not mean for me that the resulting pulse shaped signal has maxima with 9 samples between them. We can see on the plot of the signal after the constellation modulator that at 1ms, 2ms, 3ms,... we have our symbols with amplitudes of approximately 0,7.

Comment: For info, I have just added in my question an other edit where I use a FIR RRC block instead of the polyphase clock sync block. With it it does work perfectly but there is no synchronization. It makes me think the problem comes from the polyphase clock sync block and not from the constellation modulator block. What do you think?

Comment: can you use the *interpolating FIR filter block* (interpolation=10) with RRC taps on BPSK symbols (e.g. from a vector source giving you random +1 and -1)?

Comment: By the way, I'm fairly confident the sync works – it's actually a very fine piece of work. [Instructional Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMEfx_l5Oxk) of the author.

Comment: The polyphase clock sync block does work (Tom Rondeau wrote it), but it's loop filter defaults to being heavily overdamped.  The symbol sync block (which I wrote) can be set up to be like the pfb clock sync block, but without the bug of being overdamped by default.  The PFB clock sync block can't actually output more than 2 samples/symbol, IIRC.  The symbol sync block actually can output at greater rates.  If you use the symbol sync block, plot the output and all of the diagnostic outputs on one plot to check/verify the convergence.

Comment: BTW, the ML approximation TED in the PFB clock sync block has a built in assumption in its derivation that the magnitude of the input signal is considerably less than 1.0.  Your input signal appears to be violating that assumption, so the TED will consistently overestimate the timing error

Comment: I have just read the page instruction about the block Symbol Sync (https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Symbol_Sync) that I will try to use. If I understand, I have to put a FIR RRC filter (matched filtering) + Sync Block to replace the PFB clock sync block?
Also : it is said that the input signal has to be peaked at the symbol centers but for me this is not the case. Indeed, let us imagine we send a sequence of 1 : The peaks will be exactly in the middle of the symbols because of the convolution between the original symbols and the Raised Cosine. Do you agree?

Comment: Watch the instructional video Marcus mentioned, it's explained there: You can *either* combine Symbol+Sync plus matched filter but then the matched filter must be differentiable (i.e., if you have an NRZ signal and your matched filter is the rect filter, this is not the case. You can still use a sub-optimal matched filter (RC or triangle)). Otherwise, yes, you use a separate matched filter after which the peaks will be exactly in the middle. Then you can use Symbol Sync with the normal polypase or MMSE filter.